How to Recreate this Scroll Animation using Vue JS / Nuxt JS
I created this scroll effect using vanilla html, css, and js. But I need to marry this into an existing Nuxt project. Im having a hard time getting this to work on a vue/nuxt setup.
If anyone could shed some ideas or an example it'd be greatly appreciated.
In a nutshell, I want the viewer to scroll for a certain distance and the video sequence is playing in the background. Once the user reaches the end of the animation the content below comes into view and the page will behave as a normal page.
Note: The video sequence should play in reverse as you scroll up the page. Just as it is on my html/css/js example.


const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 100;
const currentFrame = index => (
   `https://medgeclients.com/majestic/seq/${index.toString().padStart(4, '')}.jpg`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
   for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = currentFrame(i);
   }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width = 1920;
canvas.height = 1080;
img.onload = function () {
   context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

const updateImage = index => {
   img.src = currentFrame(index);
   context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
   const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
   const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
   const frameIndex = Math.min(
      frameCount - 1,
      Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
   );
   console.log(maxScrollTop);
   requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1));
});

preloadImages()
:root {
   --fromTop: calc((28826 / 1.1) * 1px);
}

* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
}

canvas {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
   z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   z-index: 9999;
}

.overlay {
   background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(13, 14, 53, 0.9), rgba(13, 14, 53, 0.5), transparent);
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 70%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 2;
}

.content {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 3;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   padding-left: 5vw;
}

.content * {
   color: red;
   text-shadow: 0 0 8px #050529;
}

.moreStuff {
   background: #ffffff;
   position: relative;
   left: 0;
   top: var(--fromTop);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 100px 50px 1500px;
   z-index: 99999;
}
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="content">
         <h1>Some overlaying Text</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, deserunt.</p>
         <a href="#firstEl">Skip animation</a>
      </div>
      <canvas id="hero-lightpass" />
   </div>

   <div id="firstEl" class="moreStuff">
      <p>#1 Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In sed consequuntur excepturi sapiente cupiditate dicta eos ut officiis a consequatur, labore nam velit enim, quibusdam error tenetur voluptatibus corrupti quasi asperiores</p>
   </div>



